# Laravel One to Many of One to Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I'm doing a project with:

- Invoice->hasMany Items
- Item->hasMany SubItems

My code is:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find($id);
foreach($invoice->items as $item) {
    $item->subItems;
}
return $invoice;
```

This works well until an Invoice has too many Items and each Items has too many SubItems and PHP return with a timeout. Does anybody have any other better solution?

Comment: For what reason do you run that `foreach` loop?

Comment: since I have no better idea to get the subItems relation.

Comment: But what do you need them for if you do nothing with them?

Comment: I need the relation subItems into item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$invoice = Invoice::with('items.subItems')->find($id);
```

and in Invoice model:

```
public function items() { 
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'foreign_id', 'id')->orderBy('rank');
}
```

in Items model:

```
public function subItems() {
    return $this->hasMany(SubItem::class, 'foreign_id', 'id')->where('rank' ,$this->rank);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The relations are lazy loaded, so for each item a new database connection is opened. This takes some time.

You can eager load the relations with: `Invoice::with('subitems')->find($id)`.
More about this at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading.

Comment: this may speed up the process, but if the speedup is not enough it will still timeout isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you have a mistake in your code. Instead of `$invoice->$items`, you probably meant `$invoice->items`.

The answer to your question could be to do eager load. Instead of:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find($id);
```

try:

```
$invoice = Invoice::with([
'items' => function ($q) {
    $q->with('subItems');
    }
])->find($id);
```

This way everything will be loaded in one query. You are currently doing `count($invoice->items) + 1` queries. This is called the N + 1 problem and it is very common and important to be aware of.

Comment: Do we have to define something else? my current relation for Invoice is: 
`public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'id', 'id')->orderBy('items.rank');
    }`
and relation on Item
`public function subItems(){
        return $this->hasMany(SubItem::class, 'id', 'id')
            ->where('sub_items.rank' ,$this->rank);
    }`
and it does not return subItem.

Comment: You are defining the relationship wrong. `Item::class` as the first argument is ok, but the following 2 arguments are not `'id', 'id'`. The second argument should be the foreign_key and the third argument should be local_key. Probably like this: `$this->hasMany(Item::class, 'item_id', 'id')->orderBy('items.rank');`. And for the sub items I am going to make a wild guess based on your function: `$this->hasMany(SubItem::class, 'rank', 'rank')`. Take a look at this page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships.

Comment: Print the sql query and try to find what is the problem. If you can't, post the query here. You can print it by replacing `->find($id)` with `->toSql()`. You will be missing the WHERE id = $id clause but you can add it manually.

Answer (score 1):

```
$invoice = Invoice::with(array('items','items.subItems')->where('id',$id)->get();
```

Comment: Can you explain further how this solves the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase - Invoices has many items and items has many sub items. We have to defined this relation in model first. "with(array('items.subItems')"  means nested relationships. you can learn more about nested relation from https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/retrieving-nested-relationships

Comment: @SopheakdeyMoeun - I have created same example for fetching user's post with their comments. You can see the example from https://github.com/sapna-bhayal/post_comment/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php. It is similar to your problem. You will definitely get help from there.

Answer (score 0):

Update the time allowed with [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) for the thread as each item is iterated over:

```
$invoice = Invoice::find($id);
$allowed_seconds_per_row = 3;
foreach($invoice->$items as $item){
    set_time_limit($allowed_seconds_per_row);
    $item->subItems();
}
return $invoice;
```

This still means a request will be taking a large amount of time, but it will only take `$allowed_seconds_per_row` seconds per row iterated over.  If one row takes longer than expected it will sill time out.

Other options are to move the process to `cli` and adjust the max execution time for that to account for the worst case.